# How do I distribute 5 points evenly onto an irregular shape?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Here is a problem I am trying to solve:

I have an irregular shape. How would I go about evenly distributing 5 points on this shape so that the distance between each point is equal to each other?

Comment: This is one of those cases where a picture is definitely worth 1000 words.

Comment: You mean pick an arbitrary point along the edge of a shape, then place 4 more points, each 1/5 of the total perimeter from the last? Or by points do you mean vertices?

Comment: Yes, and what is your distance function?

Comment: nope. not homework :-p @Paul . although, geometry was* never my strong point :)

Comment: You need to clarify what distances between which points are equal.  If you have three points, they can be placed in an equilateral triangle so the distance between any two is the same as any other two.  However, four or more points cannot be so placed (in 2D).  Etc.  So clarifications definitely needed.

Comment: @Rob i don't have one. at the risk of sounding stupid: do i need one?

Comment: @saliem You do have one - I think we can all guess you're using the usual Euclidean metric.

Comment: @Jefromi, Yes maybe, but does the distance trace the path of the shape, or can it cross open space (inside or outside the shape)?

Comment: This is too poorly-defined for me to believe it's homework.  I suspect he means something like: keeping the points a similar distance from their nearest neighbors, and also keeping a similar distance from the edges (else you could pick a small region within any image and simply distribute inside that).  If you can't define the problem better, maybe it'd be easier to tell us what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Since you can't describe your problem mathematically you should describe the concrete problem you have.

Comment: @starblue @Glenn the Yelp API allows for 20 business review responses for a given location/neighborhood. I know that for some neighborhoods there are more than 20 businesses. At first I used just the name of the neighborhood and the city. Since that didn't give me all of the results listed on the website, I printed out a map of the neighborhood and place 8-14 dots. The dots are cross streets. Then I sent my requests to include a radius and a cross street. After some tweaking that gave me 60+. I wanted to automate most of this process. I think I've found a better way though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is mathematically impossible. It will only work for a small subset of base shapes.

There are however some solutions you might try:

1. Analytic approach. Start with a point P0, create a sphere around P0 and intersect it with the base shape, giving you a set of curves C0. Then create another point P1 somewhere on C0. Again, create a sphere around P1 and intersect it with C0, giving you a set of points C1, your third point P2 will be one of the points in C1. And so on and so forth. This approach guarantees distance constraints, but it also heavily depends on initial conditions.
2. Iterative approach. Essentially form-finding. You create some points on the object and you also create springs between the ones that share a distance constraint. Then you solve the spring forces and move your points accordingly. This will most likely push them away from the base shape, so you need to pull them back onto the base shape. Repeat until your points are no longer moving or until the distance constraint has been satisfied within tolerance.
3. Sampling approach. Convert your base geometry into a voxel space, and start scooping out all the voxels that are too close to a newly inserted point. This makes sure you never get two points too close together, but it also suffers from tolerance (and probably performance) issues.

If you can supply more information regarding the nature of your geometry and your constraints, a more specific answer becomes possible.

Comment: What base shapes are you talking about? There is no way to place five points in space (of at most three dimensions) and have all pairwise distances equal. This is easy to see from the analytic approach you mention. The first three points (ABC) will form an equilateral triangle; the next (D) will make it a regular tetrahedron. When you try to place the fifth (E), if you make it equidistant from ABC, it will either be at D or the reflection of D over the plane defined by ABC, and then DE will not be the correct distance.

Comment: i'm not entirely sure what you mean by the nature of the geometry and the constraints...but the irregular shape is a locality / neighborhood. the nodes are latitude and longitude points

Comment: @Jefromi; you cannot have ALL points be an equal distance from each other, but if you have 5 points and 10 distance constraints, a solution *might* be possible.

Comment: So we're working on the surface of the earth? Are we measuring distances along the edge of the shape (not the usual metric!), or directly (on a sphere, also not the usual metric!)? Do we want every single pairwise distance equal, or are we just looking for AB = BC = CD = DE = EA?

Comment: @saliem; by the nature of the shape I mean the definition of it. Is it a mathematical surface? Is it a freeform surfaces defined as a triangular mesh, or perhaps a Nurbs patch. Is your surface continuous, closed, smooth, G1? etc. etc.

By the nature of the constraints I mean just the basic information. How many constraints do you have. Are they all the same distance, or different distances. Is there tolerance involved in your problem?

Comment: Exactly David - by having specific geometries that are not necessarily standard 3-d geometries, you can get this behavior.  It cannot happen in a standard Euclidean 3d.

Comment: Five points with equal distance from each other is easily possible in four dimensional space. The vertices of a regular 4-simplex have all the same distance from each other. So the claim "is mathematically impossible" is not true unless you specify "in three or less dimensions".

Comment: Center points "of equisized areas" (not equidistant) would be what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 10):

David says this is impossible, but in fact there is an answer out of left field: just **put all your points on top of each other**! They'll all have the same distance to all the other points: zero.

In fact, that's the only algorithm that has a solution (i.e. all pairwise distances are the same) regardless of the input shape.

I know the question asks to put the points "evenly", but since that's not formally defined, I expect that was just an attempt to explain "all pairwise distances are the same", in which case my answer is "even".

Answer (score 3):

For folks stumbling across here in the future, check out [Lloyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm).

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but it only works for a regular shape such as a rectangle.

Comment: Look into Lloyd's relaxation algorithm. The algorithm is a boundary checking one and you can add fake walls.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to position 5 points equally distant from one another (other than the trivial solution of putting them through the origin) is in the 4+ dimensional space. It is mathematically impossible to have 5 equally distanced object in 3D. 
Four is the most you can have in 3D and that shape is a tetrahedron.